# Passing QueryParams to UI.Router's ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, query-string, ui-sref

Give the following state:

```
.$stateProvider.state( 'dashboard', {
    url: '/home?layout',
    templateProvider: function($templateFactory, $state){
          ....
    }
})
```

...when using `ui-sref` in a template why does this not work?

```
<a ui-sref="dashboard({layout:'cards'})"> Card View </a>
<a ui-sref="dashboard({layout:'list'})"> List View </a>
```

I know that the query params are being evaluated properly because I've test it via

```
 $state.href('dashboard', {layout:'cards'})
```

which gives me `#/home?layout=cards` as well as navigated to this state by changing the URL. What's the catch?

Comment: does these anchors placed inside `ng-app` div? otherwise it should work

Comment: @PankajParkar: yes. The templates are loaded fine for the states, it's just the links are incorrect as they seem undefined.  Basically it seems that you can't queryParams into uiSref's state params.

Comment: did you try this ?? `dashboard({layout:cards})` it should work

Comment: syntax looks fine.  do you get error in console when you click on it?

Comment: @plong0, no, no error. I ended up changing something, then changing it back and it worked so I'm guessing I had some sort of syntax error.  I didn't copy & paste into the question exactly like it is in my code base either.  Thanks for the suggestions folks.